# python mongoengine mapping to the existing collection

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm very new to the mongo engine and having a bit of a trouble understanding how exactly it functions - documentation provided is not that straight forward. I have already collection in Mongo where each document has certain fields. I mapped these fields to the fields in the derived from the document class and referenced collection as per alias.

```
class imported_item(me.Document):
    _id = me.ObjectIdField(required = True)
    _type = me.StringField(max_length=10)
    _name = me.StringField(max_length=10)

def item_print(self):
    print ("************************************************")
    print self._id
    print self._type
    print self._name

    me.meta = {
        'db_alias': 'test',
        'index_background': True,
        'indexes': [(_type, 1),(_name, 1)],
        }

  def main():
     me.register_connection(alias="test", name=_database, host=_host, port=_port, username=_username, password=_password)

     print imported_item.objects({imported_item._type:'sm_tags'})
     imported_item.item_print()
```

Now the trouble I'm getting into is that:
1) Mongoengine complains that it requires default connection, not the one I called test, which is not what I am looking for as I will have several collections and I would like to have several object types linked to each collection, so I can work with them in parallel
2) I have a bunch of objects of mongoengine.fields.StringField coming out in the print, but not values
3) If I am trying to fetch all objects with imported_item.objects.all(), then it comes back with an empty set.

I use to _mysql driver and it was more procedure-based, hence I don't understand at what level linking between DB and mongoengine is happening and how exactly I can access the values in the DB.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your example code is indented correctly however, to look at the points.

1) You need to connect to a database - you've registered one but haven't connected to it. You can use `get_connection` to fetch a connection by its alias.

```
from mongoengine.connection import get_connection
get_connection(alias)
```

2) Your print method looks fine. However, it needs to be called on an instance of the class - its not a static method - try:

```
imported_item.objects({imported_item._type:'sm_tags'}).first().item_print()
```

3) If its coming back as an empty set because you haven't set the meta correctly - it should be a attribute of the Document class - not trying to set `me.meta` eg:

```
meta = {
    'db_alias': 'test',
    'index_background': True,
    'indexes': [(_type, 1),(_name, 1)],
    }
```

Finally - please look to pep8 for your syntax and conforming to python coding standards which are accepted community wide for python.